# Mongodb with Node.js How To Query Data From Subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to figure out how to get the data for, "openingTime" schema, which is a sub document in "location" schema

```
var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    days: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    opening: String,
    closing: String,
    closed: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        "default": 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    facilities: [String],
    // Always store coordinates longitude, latitude order.
    coords: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});
```

Then when I try to query the data

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Loc = mongoose.model('Location');

/* GET a location by the id */
module.exports.locationsReadOne = function(req, res) {
 // begin request to return single location information
 // received from app_server's getLocationInfo()
  var result = [];

  if (req.params && req.params.locationid) {
      Loc
        .findById(req.params.locationid)
        .exec(function(err, location) {
          if (!location) {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
              "message": "locationid not found"
            });
            return;
          } else if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
            return;
          }

          console.log("\n\n about to try to query open time id: ");
          console.log(location.openingTimes[0]);
          console.log("\n\n\n");

          try{ 
            result.push({

              rating: location.rating,              
              facilities: location.facilities,
              _id: location._id,
              name: location.name,
              address: location.address,
              coords: location.coords,
              openingTimes: location.openingTimes,
              reviews: location.reviews,
              __v: location.__v
            });
          }
          catch(e){
              console.log("Did not find object:  ending loop.  "+e);
          } 

          console.log(result);
          sendJSONresponse(res, 200, result);
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log('No locationid specified');
        sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
          "message": "No locationid in request"
        });
      }
  };
```

I get the following output:

```
About to try to query open time id:
{ _id: 5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c42 }


[ { rating: 0,
    facilities: ["Hot drinks","Food","Clean Bathroom","Some sitting"],
    _id: 5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c40,
    name: 'Peets Coffee',
    address: '200 Park Street, Marcone, IL 94872',
    coords: [-322.2991,37.4096],
    openingTimes: CoreMongooseArray [ [Object], [Object] ],
    reviews: CoreMongooseArray [],
    __v: 0 } ]
```

how do I get the actual data inside the "OpeningTime" array?  I tried using, .populate('openingTime') and it just gives me the _id

Answer (score 0):

Your "OpeningTime" array have an actual data's while you printing your data you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: No luck!  I continue to get the, "_id" value after stringify.... see output pasted below

About to try to query open time id:
{"_id":"5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c42"}

Here is the code to output the above value:

var opentimedata = JSON.stringify(location.openingTimes[0]);
          console.log("\nAbout to try to query open time id: ");
          console.log(opentimedata);
          console.log("\n");

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that although I created a sub-document and obtained an Id when inserting a new document, the sub-document data did not save.  I need to update the parent and find out a way to make the sub-document data save.  Here is how I found out my problem:

```
Loc
      .findById(req.params.locationid)
      .select('openingTimes')  //you can also try to populate()
      .exec(function(err, location) {
        console.log("\n\n");
        console.log("Length of opening times array is: "+location.openingTimes.length);
        var thisOpenTime = location.openingTimes.id(req.params.reviewid);             
        console.log("\nThe actual data is: "+thisOpenTime);
        console.log("\n\n");
      });
```

doing a findById().select('column').exec(...)

GET /api/locations/5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c40 200 80.179 ms - 320

// outputs the following:

opening times data is:
[ { _id: '5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c42' },
  { _id: '5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c41' } ]
GET /location/5b6f26b7a0232b6e907d1c40/ 500 632.998 ms - 3621

"Length of opening times array is: 2

The actual data is: null"

Since, I got a null this means there is no data in the sub-doc. array.